# Arkit Multi-peer function for Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit, multipeer-connectivity

It looks as if I can use the Multi-Peer features of Arkit with my Unity project to be deployed on iOS.  Apple states in its example that Realitykit is only the renderer and ARkit handles the multi-peer.  Should I assume that since we are already using ARkit in our Unity project that we would make the calls for collaboration within Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Try this repo https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/tree/main/Assets/Scenes/ARKit/ARCollaborationData.

But in order to use MultipeerConnectivity in Unity, you will need a native Unity plugin for that.